# How to synchronize all the phone contacts with my app

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my application I want to show an option like **Sync Contacts with App**.
It should synchronize all the contacts with my app (Just like Facebook does when we go to the **Contact** tab of **Find Friends** page).

So when all the contacts are synchronized, I'll match the contacts with the server and the latter will return all the members which are in my contact list as well as those ones registered on the server but not in my friends list.

So can anyone help me?
How to synchronize the device contacts with my application?

Answer (score 1):

You should create sync adapter and inside that you should sync and observe content provider for contacts.

For detailed explanation you can take reference from below reference.
http://blogs.quovantis.com/syncing-contacts-with-an-android-application-2/

Answer (score 1):

For Syncing the contacts, you will require to get all the contacts from your contact list. Then you need to get the contacts from your server and compare contacts from both the places and choose the common ones.

Here is code for getting contacts from your Contact list.

```
public void getPhoneNumbers() {
        String PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{PHONE_NUMBER}, null, null, null);
        ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String number = cur.getString(0);
            number = number.replaceAll(" ", "");
            if (!phones.contains(number)) phones.add(number);
        }
        cur.close();
    }
```

Since i don't know your server side code, i cannot help you in getting your contacts from the server but a simple query should do the job and matching the contacts will require for loop inside a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html), it's pretty well explained there, and not very difficult. Then, if you still have some problems when implementing it, just come back here and ask for a concrete help with your code.

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a `SyncAdapter`, if you want to sync your contacts with your application. If you don't add it, then Contacts won't be shown. When you add the sync adapter you will also need an Authenticator.

Answer (score -1):

So you mean you want to sync the local data with the server data?

- Build the connection between local data and server data.
- Load from server and check the local data./ Upload the local data to server and the server check the data and mark it.

It depends on you situation. Just like the relation. You can use the phone number to build the connection between two person. If Jack has registered, so your server has Jack's phone number and his id. When Mary register, the client upload mary's local contacts. Then the server check the data. Having found Jack's phone, that means Jack is Mary's friend. So when Jack or Mary load the 'Frinds', it shows the data.